# module 'sys' has no attribute 'setExecutionLimit'

Tags: python

```
import sys
sys.setExecutionLimit(60000)
```

this code gives me this error:

```
sys.setExecutionLimit(60000)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-6f700cfa2531>", line 1, in <module>
    sys.setExecutionLimit(60000)

AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setExecutionLimit'
```

Why I am seeing this error, and how should I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason to expect that the `sys` module has this function? (it doesn't)

Comment: @Kris I also thought that, however I see that a lot of people and a lot of tutorials are using that. The only other info I could find was a comment in one page which says " setExecutionLimit is not in the standard sys-module!" But I could not find where else are they getting that different sys module from!

Comment: Well presumable you're importing from some other modules as well. Try those.

Comment: I mean... there must be a reason why you're calling the `setExecutionLimit` function, right? If it's not defined in your script, you must import it from somewhere.

Comment: The `sys` module that *does* define `setExecutionLimit()` is the one that's part of Skulpt, an online browser-based implementation of the Python language.  If you're using using standard Python on your own computer, then there is absolutely no need for this function - your code can take as long to run as it wants.

Comment: @Kris i assume that he will be calling that function so the program does not raise a RecursionError due to excessive recursion.

Comment: @jasonharper But sometimes even our computer raise the RecursionError as it cannot handle so many recursions

Comment: @VanshSachdeva: You're thinking of an unrelated function that manages an unrelated limit.

Comment: @VanshSachdeva Wouldn't it be called setRecusionLimit in that case? Also, I suspect this is related to a general misunderstanding of a piece of code not written by the person themself.

Comment: @Kris you can check the sys module. its setrecursionlimit().

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I have also come across this recursion error. And this line resolved that for me.

Comment: @VanshSachdeva: `sys.setrecursionlimit` is a thing that exists, but it is not the thing the question is asking about. It's a different thing with a similar name. Similarly, the question is not asking about recursion errors.

Comment: ☝️ exactly. Thanks @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ok. So can you tell me the exact difference between the two functions?

Comment: @VanshSachdeva: One is a Skulpt function that manages time limits. The other is a Python function that manages call stack depth limits.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica OOhk. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `sys.setExecutionLimit` in standard Python. That function is part of [Skulpt](https://skulpt.org/), a Javascript-based implementation of something somewhat resembling Python 2.

In Skulpt, `sys.setExecutionLimit` manages execution time limits, which standard Python does not have.

Python *does* have the completely unrelated function [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit), which manages the maximum call stack depth Python will allow before throwing a RecursionError. (Note that setting a high recursion limit will usually just turn Python stack overflows into C stack overflows, which are much messier and harder to debug.)

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering from where do so many tutorials are using that method!
I have seen lot of your good answers & comments. As an aside, what does '..supports Monica' mean?

Comment: @lllrnr101: There was a big thing a while back where Stack Exchange abruptly fired a popular moderator named Monica. It got a lot of people angry, especially since it was part of a long chain of other widely-disliked company actions.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.setExecutionLimit()` is a custom sys method created for the Runestone environment and used in U of M Coursera classes such as "Python Classes and Inheritance".  It is not a standard `sys` method (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

Runestone does not have a way to interrupt a kernel the way, for example, Jupyter has.  I'm guessing this is why the Runestone team created this custom system method.  `sys.setExecutionLimit(60000)` will kill the kernel 60 minutes later so that your code doesn't keep running ad infinitum.

When recreating your homework outside of Runestone, don't use `sys.setExecutionLimit()`.